Failed to play MP3 audio with ffmpeg API in Linux
I am working on an audioplayer by using FFMPEG libaray, and ALSA.
The following codes failed to playback the MP3 media smoothly (it is slower and noisy), I checked the FFMPEG codes and examples, but I did not the right solutions.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

#include <libswresample/swresample.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>

int init_pcm_play(snd_pcm_t **playback_handle,snd_pcm_uframes_t chunk_size,unsigned int rate,int bits_per_sample,int channels)
{
    snd_pcm_hw_params_t *hw_params;
    snd_pcm_format_t format;

    //1. openPCM，
    if (0 > snd_pcm_open(playback_handle, "default", SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0))
    {
        printf("snd_pcm_open err\n");
        return -1;
    }
    //2. snd_pcm_hw_params_t
    if(0 > snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc (&hw_params))
    {
        printf("snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc err\n");
        return -1;
    }
    //3. hw_params
    if(0 > snd_pcm_hw_params_any (*playback_handle, hw_params))
    {
        printf("snd_pcm_hw_params_any err\n");
        return -1;
    }
    //4.
    if (0 > snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access (*playback_handle, hw_params, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED))
    {
        printf("snd_pcm_hw_params_any err\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //5. SND_PCM_FORMAT_U8,8
    if(8 == bits_per_sample) {
        format = SND_PCM_FORMAT_U8;
    }
    if(16 == bits_per_sample) {
        format = SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE;
    }
    if (0 > snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format (*playback_handle, hw_params, format))
    {
        printf("snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format err\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //6.
    if (0 > snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near (*playback_handle, hw_params, &rate, 0))
    {
        printf("snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near err\n");
        return -1;
    }
    //7.
    if (0 > snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(*playback_handle, hw_params, 2))
    {
        printf("snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels err\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //8. set hw_params
    if (0 > snd_pcm_hw_params (*playback_handle, hw_params))
    {
        printf("snd_pcm_hw_params err\n");
        return -1;
    }

    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(hw_params, &chunk_size, 0);

    snd_pcm_hw_params_free (hw_params);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL; //for opening multi-media file
    int audioStream = -1;
    AVCodecContext *pCodecCtx = NULL;
    AVCodec *pCodec = NULL; // the codecer
    AVFrame *pFrame = NULL;
    AVPacket *packet;
    uint8_t *out_buffer;
    struct SwrContext *au_convert_ctx;
    snd_pcm_t *playback_handle;
    int bits_per_sample = 0;

    if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, argv[1], NULL, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("Failed to open video file!");
        return -1; // Couldn't open file
    }

    if(avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx,NULL)<0)
    {
        printf("Failed to find stream info.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    audioStream = av_find_best_stream(pFormatCtx, AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO, -1, -1, NULL, 0);
    if (audioStream == -1) {
        printf("Din't find a video stream!");
        return -1;// Didn't find a video stream
    }

    av_dump_format(pFormatCtx, audioStream, NULL, false);

    // Find the decoder for the video stream
    pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(pFormatCtx->streams[audioStream]->codecpar->codec_id);
    if (pCodec == NULL) {
        printf("Unsupported codec!\n");
        return -1; // Codec not found
    }

    // Copy context
    pCodecCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(pCodec);
    AVCodecParameters *pCodecParam = pFormatCtx->streams[audioStream]->codecpar;

     if (avcodec_parameters_to_context(pCodecCtx, pCodecParam) < 0) {
        printf("Failed to set codec params\n");
        return -1;
    }
    // Open codec
    if (avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, NULL) < 0) {
        printf("Failed to open decoder!\n");
        return -1; // Could not open codec
    }
    packet = av_packet_alloc();
    pFrame = av_frame_alloc();

    uint64_t iInputLayout                    = av_get_default_channel_layout(pCodecCtx->channels);
    enum AVSampleFormat eInputSampleFormat   = pCodecCtx->sample_fmt;
    int         iInputSampleRate             = pCodecCtx->sample_rate;


    uint64_t iOutputLayout                   = av_get_default_channel_layout(pCodecCtx->channels);
    int      iOutputChans                    = pCodecCtx->channels;
    enum AVSampleFormat eOutputSampleFormat  = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16;
    int         iOutputSampleRate            = pCodecCtx->sample_rate;

    au_convert_ctx = swr_alloc_set_opts(NULL,iOutputLayout, eOutputSampleFormat, iOutputSampleRate,
        iInputLayout,eInputSampleFormat, iInputSampleRate, 0, NULL);
    swr_init(au_convert_ctx);
    int iConvertLineSize = 0;
    int iConvertBuffSize  = av_samples_get_buffer_size(&iConvertLineSize, iOutputChans, pCodecCtx->frame_size, eOutputSampleFormat, 0);
    printf("ochans: %d, ifrmsmp: %d, osfmt: %d, cbufsz: %d\n", iOutputChans, pCodecCtx->frame_size, eOutputSampleFormat, iConvertBuffSize);
    out_buffer = (uint8_t *) av_malloc(iConvertBuffSize);

    if(eOutputSampleFormat == AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16 )
    {
        bits_per_sample = 16;
    }
    /*** alsa handle ***/
    init_pcm_play(&playback_handle,256, iOutputSampleRate,bits_per_sample,2);

    if (0 > snd_pcm_prepare (playback_handle))
    {
        printf("snd_pcm_prepare err\n");
        return -1;
    }

    while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, packet) >= 0) {
        if (packet->stream_index == audioStream) {
            avcodec_send_packet(pCodecCtx, packet);
            while (avcodec_receive_frame(pCodecCtx, pFrame) == 0) {
                int outframes = swr_convert(au_convert_ctx, &out_buffer, pCodecCtx->frame_size, (const uint8_t **) pFrame->data, pFrame->nb_samples); // 转换音频
                snd_pcm_writei(playback_handle, out_buffer, outframes);
                av_frame_unref(pFrame);
            }
        }
        av_packet_unref(packet);
    }
    swr_free(&au_convert_ctx);
    snd_pcm_close(playback_handle);
    av_freep(&out_buffer);

    return 0;
}

Running the codes can show following logs.
./ap_alsa ./dooralarm.mp3
[mp3 @ 0x1e72020] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from '(null)':
  Metadata:
    genre           : Blues
    id3v2_priv.XMP  : <?xpacket begin="\xef\xbb\xbf" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>\x0a<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.3-c011 66.145661, 2012/02/06-14:56:27        ">\x0a <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">\x0a  <rdf
  Duration: 00:00:05.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 58 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 22050 Hz, mono, fltp, 48 kb/s
ochans: 1, ifrmsmp: 576, osfmt: 1, cbufsz: 1152

I am using the FFMPEG-4.4.4, and Linux-kernel-5.10.20.
